# li tag, IE7 and text in one line (row)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have text in `<li>` tags, and I would like to show this text in one line.

With Firefox is good, but IE7, no. In IE7 I must give the `<li>` elements a `width`. But text can be very long or short. so this no good to me: `width 50px;`

```
#menu_all li{
    float:left;
    display: block-inline;
    padding:0;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
<div id="menu_all">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="text">Text</span></li>
        <li><span class="text">Text2</span></li>
        <li><span class="text">Text2 text text</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How make that `<li>` menu show well in IE7 on one line?

Thanks

Comment: I have: display: block-inline;, so it is the sime like: display: inline;

Comment: Block-inline is not the same as inline.

Comment: It's actually inline-block; not block-inline; and IE7 doesn't seem to support that. so try inline insted it will work. And yeah is not the same as display: inline;

Comment: Setting `float: left` and `display: inline-block` at the same time makes no sense. A floated element is always a block element. Choose one. Either should work. If it's not, you are leaving something relevant out. Also you should mention is you are in standards or quirksmode.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like an error in your CSS. It's `display: inline-block;` not `display: block-inline;`.

Revised code:

```
#menu_all li
{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

<div id="menu_all">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="text">Text</span></li>
        <li><span class="text">Text2</span></li>
        <li><span class="text">Text2 text text</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand this question, you need this;

```
#menu_all ul li{ display: list-item;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Like this:**

```
 #menu_all ul li{
        float: left;
        display: inline;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    }
    <div id="menu_all">
        <ul>
            <li><span class="text">Text</span></li>
            <li><span class="text">Text2</span></li>
            <li><span class="text">Text2 text text</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `display: block-inline;` is wrong - it should be `display: inline-block;`.

Secondly, using `display` and `float` in the same style is un-necessary. `float` turns the display mode to `block` automatically. (But I always prefer to use `inline-block` instead of `float` wherever possible, as `float` has a number of other annoying quirks)

Finally, `inline-block` mode has a bug in older versions of IE (IE6 and IE7) which means that it only works for elements which have a native display style of `inline`.

This means you have a major problem for using `inline-block` if you need to support IE6 or IE7. It works for some tags but not others.

Fortunately, there is a quick work-around. IE7 treats `inline` basically the same as `inline-block`, so for IE7 you can get away with just specifying `display:inline;`. but it does mean using a yukky CSS hack to make it work for all cases:

```
.mystyle {
    display:inline-block;
     /*next two lines IE7-hack*/
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
}
```

(The `zoom:1;` is also an IE-specific style which is a round-about way of hacking IE to display it in the correct mode)

The alternative to the star hack would be to use IE's conditional comments feature to specify these styles for IE7, but that can also be quite nasty.

By the way, for more information about browser support for the `display` style, see this page on Quirksmode.org:  http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html